# How can I make Seamonkey the default Web and E-Mail client in Precise?

Tags: email, seamonkey

I've installed Seamonkey 2.14.1 via Ubuntuzilla, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it the default Mail and Web clients.  If I click on a web link in the Seamonkey News or Mail reader it launches the link in Seamonkey as I'd expect.  However, if I click on a link outside of Seamonkey, it'll launch Google Chrome (which somehow made itself my default browser). Can anyone help?

I don't like Firefox/Thunderbird... I uninstalled both immediately after installing Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Launch "System Settings" from the Dash.
2. Click on "Details" in the "System" group (at the bottom).
3. Select "Default Applications" from the list on the left.

From there you can choose Seamonkey as default application for web and email.

Comment: I've tried that.  I click on the dropdown for "Web" and my only choice is "Google Chrome" and the "Mail" drop down is grayed out. That's why I was asking here.  Thanks.